# How to set the vertical length of xib as code in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to modify the height of the View in Xib Size Inspector flexibly in the code.

I also want to modify the Height Equals in Constraints in the UICollectionView in Xib.

Short Code :

```
class ShopImagesViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // ......
    }
}

extension ShopImagesViewCell
{
    func setView(urls : [String], isZzip : Bool)
    {
        self.imageCollectionView.delegate = self
        self.imageCollectionView.dataSource = self
        self.imageCollectionView.regCells(cells: 
        ["ShopImageCollectionViewCell","ShopNonImageCollectionViewCell"])
        // ......
    }
}

extension ShopImagesViewCell : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return CGFloat(291) // It does not work.
    }
}
```

When Xib is first loaded, it is executed only once to fit in size.

Modifying Xib height length in code and modifying the Height Equals of Constraintsd in UICollectionView in code.

Please tell me where I should use the code.

Comment: Where is the code adjusting the height? Also, if you are using auto layout, it is a best practice to not adjust the frame.

Comment: where is your code to set `tableview.delegate` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to you pasted code, it seems that you placed a custom `UITableViewCell` into the nib. Assumed on that, you cannot set height directly without the help of `UITableViewDelegate`.

Where the `UITableViewDelegate` is implemented or you intended to implement add this delegate method

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // you have the indexPath based on which you can set the height dynamically, based on the cell position.
    // return your intended height here
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: extension ShopImagesViewCell: UITableViewDelegate
I paste and run the code but it does not work.

Comment: did you set tableview.delegate to your `shopImagesViewCell` class object ?

Comment: do your delegate `tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath` get even called

Comment: in your updated question, where is the code which set the `tableView.delegate` ?

Comment: I can not run my code, but I think it is a good answer. I will adopt and post new questions.